# Styling of product image using CSS

Tags: css

I have a problem regarding importing of Amazon product images.

When I see the product on Amazon, its main image container contains the squeezed image but its presentable:

link https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B004TDJANW?th=1&psc=1

When I upload these images to my website, it show the actual height and width of the images - which is not presentable!

What type of CSS should I use so that product image should not be more than my container image container on my woocommerce website?

- If height of image is greater then container height then reduce height & width by equal percent such that after reducing height of it equals to container image.
- If width of image is > then width container of image then reduce it by etc% to make it equal to width of container.also if height is < container then align it to center such that it has equal padding from top and bottom
- If height is < container then equal margin or padding from top and bottom.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can put image in a container

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="image"/>
</container>
```

and then you append these styles:

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

This way image will not be larger than 300x300 pixels

Comment: i dont have a container in elementor what should i do

Comment: create it or set max-width, max-height and display: block on your image